# Android App to get user's location information

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I would like to develop an Android app which could track the user's location information.
Let me say more details, the apps will let the members to registered, and users could make friends through the app.

The app could allow user to track(or just get) the other's location information if they would like to. For example, if user1 and user2 are friends, and user1 could request to get where the user2's location is. (I just talking about the function, if it touches the security area, please just ignore at the moment..)

But the issue comes, although I have gained how to get the own local phone's location information and send to other's phone, but how can I let user1 to get user2's information? Seems, it needs to let user2 send its information itself...

So, I am not know whether there is any way to figure it out?
Here is just the only one idea come out of my mind:

First,let all the phone user's app running all the time in the user's phone, even in their backend.

Second,set a time slot that each phone need to send the location info to the database and store.

Third,then we can search and get the location's information for other users' location info.
---does it workable?

Anyone has other suggestion? or any advice? any resource? any reference? thanks in advance!!